# How to pass a php value on a modal? bootstrap 3,

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap 3 and my coding doesnt seem to pass the php value to a modal? I usually code like this in bootstrap 2++, i decided to add data target also, this is my code:

```
<a class="btn btn-link"  
   href="#reply<?php echo $product_id; ?>" 
   data-toggle="modal" 
   data-target="#reply<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
       <i class="icon-reply"></i> 
       Reply
</a>
```

and for the modal:

```
<a class="btn btn-link"  
    href="#reply<?php echo $product_id; ?>" 
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#reply<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
         <i class="icon-reply"></i> 
         Reply 
</a>
```

what am i missing?

Comment: Please format your code properly so we can read it. Also, where is the PHP code? you are going to have to add more code so we can help

Comment: sorry i am new here, please see my edit, thank you.

Comment: ok thank you, so what is happening here? The PHP value isn't showing up?

Comment: the modal is not showing in bootstrap 3 but in bootstrap 2 it is ok,

Comment: Take a look at this migration list from 2 to 3, it mentions some changes in modal code which might be the reason you are experiencing this problem. http://getbootstrap.com/migration/#notes

Comment: "Also, you should no longer apply .hide to .modal in your markup." Are you using `.hide` on your modal? if so, i will make this into an answer

Comment: does removing the `hide` class work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [migration guide](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/#notes) from Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3, there were a few non-compatible changes made, specifically to the `modal` object. It looks like in your case, you need to remove the `hide` class from your modal in order to work in Bootstrap 3:

> > [...] you should no longer apply `.hide` to `.modal` in your markup.

Comment: thank you! it helped me the modal appears now, and still working on it